# How to Correctly use com.mattbertolini.hermes.Hermes to manage Constants at Server side (GWT)?

Tags: gwt, gwtp

Ok, I want to manage Constants at Server level, so `com.mattbertolini.hermes.Hermes` is a solution.

Please see all my steps:

1- I downloaded `hermes-1.2.0.jar` & import into correct Library of eclipse (no problem)

2- Create `MyConstantsWithLookup.java` at client package

```
import com.google.gwt.i18n.client.ConstantsWithLookup;

public interface MyConstantsWithLookup extends ConstantsWithLookup {
    String myMsg();
}
```

3- create `MyConstantsWithLookup.properties` file in the same client package. The file has this line:

```
myMsg=Deleted
```

4- In ServerData.java in Server package

```
MyConstantsWithLookup my = Hermes.get(MyConstantsWithLookup.class, "");
String  extra=my.myMsg();
```

When tested in eclipse it works fine but I got Warnign message in eclipse:

```
[WARN] Server class 'com.ibm.icu.util.ULocale' could not be found in the web app, but was found on the system classpath
   [WARN] Adding classpath entry 'file:/C:/Users/eclipse-jee-juno-SR1-win32-x86_64/eclipse/plugins/com.google.gwt.eclipse.sdkbundle_2.5.0.v201212122042-rel-r42/gwt-2.5.0/gwt-dev.jar' to the web app classpath for this session
   For additional info see: file:/C:/Users/eclipse-jee-juno-SR1-win32-x86_64/eclipse/plugins/com.google.gwt.eclipse.sdkbundle_2.5.0.v201212122042-rel-r42/gwt-2.5.0/doc/helpInfo/webAppClassPath.html
```

I am not sure what this warning's about? is it serious?

The code was running ok but why eclipse generated this warning?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This class (`com.ibm.icu.util.ULocale`) is a replacement for `java.util.Locale`, so it seems Hermes has a dependency on it.

Download the **ICU4J jar** from http://site.icu-project.org/download and add it to your project's build path.

*Source:* **Matt Bertolini** at https://github.com/mattbertolini/Hermes/issues/3

> You need to add the ICU4j jar located at http://site.icu-project.org/
>   to your classpath. The reason you have the ICU classes inside the
>   gwt-dev.jar is because GWT includes them for its Java to JavaScript
>   compiler. This is regrettable since it often times falsely reports the
>   files on your classpath.